# How to pick a value in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

My data is of the following form

```
structure(list(atp = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1), len = c(2, NA, 3, NA, 
NA, 1), Day_1 = c(8, 7, 8, 9, 6, 6), Day_2 = c(94, 94, 102, 97, 
102, 100), Day_3 = c(104, 162, 133, 142, 96, 122)), .Names = c("atp", 
"len", "Day_1", "Day_2", "Day_3"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to attain the following output

```
structure(list(atp = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1), len = c(2, NA, 3, NA, 
NA, 1), Day_1 = c(8, 7, 8, 9, 6, 6), Day_2 = c(94, 94, 102, 97, 
102, 100), Day_3 = c(104, 162, 133, 142, 96, 122), output = c(94, 
NA, 133, NA, NA, 6)), .Names = c("atp", "len", "Day_1", "Day_2", 
"Day_3", "output"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

which is basically depending on column 2 values it picks the value from column 3, 4 or 5.

I have achieved it through the following code

```
result<-cbind(y, output=apply(y, 1, function(r) r[r["len"]+2]))
```

But this process is very time taking. Is there any way to speed up the process? How can I use data.tables for this?

Comment: are you using `data.frame`s or [data.table](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html)s?

Answer (score 3):

One possible approach:

```
result <- cbind(y, 
                output = unlist(y[3:5])[nrow(y) * (y$len -1) + seq.int(nrow(y))])
```

Another one (this should be faster):

```
result <- cbind(y, output = y[3:5][cbind(seq.int(nrow(y)), y$len)])
```

Both approaches result in:

```
#   atp len Day_1 Day_2 Day_3 output
# 1   1   2     8    94   104     94
# 2   0  NA     7    94   162     NA
# 3   1   3     8   102   133    133
# 4   0  NA     9    97   142     NA
# 5   0  NA     6   102    96     NA
# 6   1   1     6   100   122      6
```

Answer (score 2):

Turns out, my solution is misleading, sorry for that.

Anyway, here's some interesting benchmarking: http://pastebin.com/adwmFRXP

For N = 1e3:

```
          test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
3       sven()          100    0.03    1.000      0.03     0.00         NA        NA
5 codoremifa()          100    0.07    2.333      0.07     0.00         NA        NA
4     shadow()          100    0.21    7.000      0.19     0.00         NA        NA
1    default()          100    0.59   19.667      0.60     0.00         NA        NA
2  tonytonov()          100    1.31   43.667      1.04     0.27         NA        NA
```

For N = 1e4:

```
          test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
3       sven()           50    0.02      1.0      0.02     0.00         NA        NA
5 codoremifa()           50    0.03      1.5      0.03     0.00         NA        NA
4     shadow()           50    0.09      4.5      0.09     0.00         NA        NA
2  tonytonov()           50    0.57     28.5      0.45     0.12         NA        NA
1    default()           50    2.93    146.5      2.93     0.00         NA        NA
```

For N = 1e5:

```
          test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
3       sven()           10    0.01        1      0.02     0.00         NA        NA
5 codoremifa()           10    0.02        2      0.02     0.00         NA        NA
4     shadow()           10    0.03        3      0.03     0.00         NA        NA
2  tonytonov()           10    0.12       12      0.11     0.02         NA        NA
1    default()           10    8.75      875      8.66     0.01         NA        NA
```

For N = 1e6:

```
          test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
3       sven()           10    0.01        1      0.02     0.00         NA        NA
5 codoremifa()           10    0.01        1      0.02     0.00         NA        NA
4     shadow()           10    0.03        3      0.03     0.00         NA        NA
2  tonytonov()           10    0.13       13      0.11     0.01         NA        NA
1    default()           10   86.73     8673     85.89     0.56         NA        NA
```

Comment: `data.table` is designed for large tables. I'd like to see the results on a table with `1e5` or preferably `1e6` rows (thought you may want to reduce the replications!). If you have smaller data then just use `base` R and Sven's solution.

Comment: @SimonO101, see update. Note that pastebin code is reproducible, so anyone can try this on arbitrary lengths.

Comment: Thanks Tony. Yes they can, but since you are posting the code and basing an answer (which should really be an edit to the OP this is not an answer in itself) on it, I think it's disingenuous to produce timings based on such a small N (which was not stated in the question). Good job though. I am unsure as to why code is getting *faster* as data is getting larger though. (oh - is elapsed the total time for all replications? That would make sense).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was not sure about where to post, will be careful next time. 
Elapsed is the total time, yes, so for different N it is correct to compare elapsed/replications ratio.

Answer (score 1):

Where dt1 is your first dataset -

```
for ( i in unique(dt1[!is.na(dt1$len),'len']))
{
  dt1[dt1$len == i & !is.na(dt1$len),'Output'] <- dt1[dt1$len == i & !is.na(dt1$len),paste0('Day_',i)]
}
```

Comment: I suppose `dt1` is a `data.frame` here?

Comment: Yep, the OP's first dataset is a data.frame as well. I now notice that they are being called data tables which is probably a slip.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer using `data.table`. This should be the fastest version for large `data.frame`'s. However, it also explicitly uses the structure of the data you provided, so it may not be that easily generalizable.

```
dt <- data.table(y)
dt[, output:=ifelse(len==1, Day_1, 
                    ifelse(len==2, Day_2, Day_3))]
```